# libcurl returns CURLE_URL_MALFORMAT with # in file name

Tags: filenames, libcurl, file-transfer, ftps

When I try to transfer file using FTPS and destination file name has character **#** in your name the transfer fail with this error:

```
3/URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
```

How inform libcurl to do not reject this character in destination file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must URL-encode any '#' symbol as %23 in the URL to make it a URL when the letter is supposed to be part of the path, as any unencoded '#' symbol will be considered marking where the "fragment" starts.

This is dictated by [RFC3986](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt).

Comment: Tomorrow I will do a test to see if it solves the case.